# Mongoose - express server update specific index in array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've created a custom `identifier` ID and I'm trying to update my coins and aswell as the first
array object purchased bool to true.

this is how my data looks like

```
[
    {
    
        "identifier": "123456789",
        "coins": 100,
        "equipments": [
            {
                "item": "itemname",
                "price": 100,
                "gold": 10,
                "level": 1,
                "condition": 100,
                "purchased": false
            },
            {
                "item": "itemname2",
                "price": 80,
                "gold": 8,
                "level": 1,
                "condition": 100,
                "purchased": false
            },
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

This is my update routes

```
router.put("/update/:identifier", function(req,res){
  User.find({identifier: req.params.identifier}, function(err, equipment) {
    equipment.coins= 50;
    equipment[0].equipments.purchased = true;
  
    equipment[0].save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
      } else {
        res.json(equipment);
      }
    });
  });
 });
```

When I run it nothing happens and it doesn't give any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the conventional approach.
You need to do it like this.

```js
router.put("/update/:identifier", function(req,res){
  User.findOne({identifier: req.params.identifier}, function(err, equipment) {
    equipment.coins= 50;
    equipment.equipments.purchased = true;
  
    equipment.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
      } else {
        res.json(equipment);
      }
    });
  });
 });
```

**BONUS**:I would suggest you to use [findAndUpdateOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)